# Android Notification click keep stack and bring app to front if need. Pass data if specific activity is on top

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-task

How can I click a notification, bring my app to the foreground if needed, and keep the stack as it was (even when the app went to the background)?

I have a `NotificationClickActivity` that is launched when the user clicks a notification.

When the notification is clicked, I have two possible scenarios:

1. User is logged out from the app
2. User is logged in.

In the first scenario, `NotificationClickActivity` starts the login process and receives the result. If OK, I launch `MainActivity`. The task is cleared so `MainActivity` is the only activity that I have in the task. I have no problems in this scenario.

In the second scenario `NotificationClickActivity` does this:

```
finish()  
startActivity(MainActivity.createIntent(this).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).putExtra("notification", notification))
```

With the above code, if the app is already running (`MainActivity` is the root and top activity) and if on the background or in the foreground, I have no problems. `MainActivity` `onNewIntent` is called and I can do whatever I what with the notification. In this case, I dispatch the notification to a repository.

The problem I'm facing is when I have activities on top of `MainActivity`. Imagine the following stack:

```
MainActivity -> ActivityOne -> ActivityTwo -> ActivityN
```

With the code that I currently have if I click the notification the stack becomes:

```
MainActivity -> ActivityOne -> ActivityTwo -> ActivityN -> MainActivity
```

I want the stack to stay `MainActivity -> ActivityOne -> ActivityTwo -> ActivityN` but still pass the notification to `MainActivity` so it can be dispatched to the repository.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

I've been playing with the intent flags for some time but without success.
Of course, I what this without any visible animations or whatever so that the user does not realize what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Think you're looking for [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

`.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP || FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`

This will bring the activity to the top of the stack if its already running.

> consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B.

In the above example, if you want to go from A,B,C,D to A,B,C,D,B instead, then you need to make sure your activity supports multiple instances.

Suggest `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to be specified in android manifest for the activity instead. Then in your `onNewIntent` you should check if the user is logged in. If the user is not, you should launch the login process with `startActivityForResult` and handle the login result with `onActivityResult`.

This assumes your login can be initiated with an intent, which calls `setResult` with enough information for the caller to determine if the login was successful.

As for animations, I think you will have to use fragments and disable animations, or disable animations for the activity, and do custom transitions only when you want it. This may even not work with activities, since the OS/OEM defined transitions may just happen with activities regardless anyway, so you'll very likely have to make sure rest of the app is in the same activity and use fragments for navigation.

---

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to reorder to front. Also, I don't have any problems when my user is logged out. I only have if he is logged in and if the stack is A, B, C, D. In this case, clicking the notification I want to keep the stack as A, B, C, D but: 1 - Pass info to A and 2 - Bring the app to the foreground if it's on the background. Another possibility would be to check whats the topmost activity.

Comment: Right. Short answer is no. Only way to pass information to an activity is to bring it back from paused state, which means it starts, and comes to the front. I believe what you want is to update some state, which A can refresh upon its next 'resume'. For this, you can use a separate activity without any UI, which handles the intent and finish. As per bringing current activity to front, may be you can make your intent more generic. Set category, and package name, but don't specify the activity. Think this is what happens when you click launcher icon. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with this approach. If the current task contains `MainActivity` and also other activities on top of that, there is no way to send an `Intent` to `MainActivity` (without removing the activities on top of `MainActivty`) using `startActivity` or by launching an `Activity`.

If you need to get information to `MainActivity` then you need to use another mechanism to do this:

- Send a broadcast `Intent` and have `MainActivity` listen for the broadcast
- Use an event bus implementation
- Use a "global variable" to pass this information between the 2 activities